# Disable Hover on Mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, hover, media-queries

I need to disable the hover effect/selector of a button, on mobile (by media query).

I have 20 or so CSS lines for `:hover` so cancelling them one by one is not an option.

`pointer-events` isn't either since it would cancel the click event as well.

I'd like a CSS only solution please.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, you can't disable it, but you can not enable it.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .desktopOnlyHover{
        background-color:salmon;
    }
}
```